# Change the CSS of an embedded website questionnaire

Tags: html, css, embed

I'll have to embed a questionnaire that was made in another website something like this:

```
<embed src="https://questionnaire.com">
```

But the questionnaire CSS doesn't fit with the rest of the website, I tried changing on the style block but it doesn't seem to apply inside the embed. Any way to do this?

Comment: Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe/217833#217833

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="https://questionnaire.com" ></iframe>
```

Comment: Doesn't work on an iframe either

Comment: check trust security on your bak-end  to allow iframe content

Comment: Check this url to understand your issue https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src

Comment: Maybe this can help understand the issue? The questionnaire was created on a third party website https://i.imgur.com/huYOcJx.png

Comment: So if he block iframe security header You couldn't  access it as iframe .